# Easiest way to solve D.E.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I was given this question in class today, 
$$y’’ -\frac{(y’)^2}{y}=y.$$
I got to $$ y\cdot y’’ -(y’)^2 -y^2 =0$$
But I mean I’m lost. I’m sure it’s a quick computation.

Comment: You could write the ODE as $\frac{y''}{y}- \frac{(y')^2}{y^2} =1$, then note that the LHS is $\left( \frac{y'}{y} \right)'$.

Comment: Yes it’s so obvious. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Avoid titles with "easiest" or "best", this is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y’’ -\frac{(y’)^2}{y}=y.$$
$$\dfrac {y’’y -{(y’)^2}}{y^2}=1$$
Then use 
$$\frac {f'g-fg'}{g^2}=\left (\frac {f}{g} \right )'$$
With $f=y'$ and $g=y$
$$\implies \left (\frac {y'}{y} \right )'=1$$
Integrate.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

When writing

$$yy''-y'^2-y^2=0$$

you are not so far, because you can notice that

$$yy''+y'^2$$

is the derivative of $yy'$. Anyway, the minus sign does not match, and you can think of a quotient. Indeed

$$\left(\frac{y'}y\right)'=\frac{yy''-y'^2}{y^2}.$$

The rest is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Compute  $$\left (\frac {y'}{y}\right)'.$$